# Looking for book with illustrations of whimsical unicycle factory

Tags: story-identification

I believe this was a book of hand-drawn illustrations, somewhat like Stephen Biesty works or Where's Waldo books. I saw it in the mid 2000s up to early 2010s. The only picture I remember was a whimsical unicycle/bicycle factory with wheels rolling down curvy yellow tracks, in a manner more like a Rube Goldberg machine instead of a realistic factory. I believe the style of drawing was "follow the path" like the kind you see on the sides of cereal boxes. There were unrealistic precariously perched platforms and colorful steam-powered and man-powered machinery that is totally unlike any realistic factory. There were workers everywhere doing various tasks like operating machinery and assembling the unicycles.

This image I found online is reminiscent of the maze-like style of the factory.

[image: online drawing]

For fun, here's DALL-E 3 with the prompt "A whimsical maze-like bicycle factory cartoon":

[image: dall-e output]

Comment: Could it be something out of Dr Seuss? His illustrations frequently included unicycles and fantastic factories.   (And I'd say this question should definitely be left open)

Comment: I added some more details I am trying to remember. @Pete I didn't think of Dr Seuss but that is a possibility.

Comment: It sounds fantastical to me.

Answer (score 4):

You may be looking for a W. Heath Robinson illustration. He was a British illustrator & cartoonist who drew intricate and complicated machines to do simple jobs (like testing golf clubs) [image: testing golf clubs]
or solve problems (like having no servants) [image: how to dispense with servants].

I haven't been able to find a bicycle factory, but he used bicycle wheels (and unicycles) a lot in his contraptions. There are also a lot of precarious perches, made of long poles tied together with a piece of knotted string.

Some of my favourite cartoons are from his series on How to live in a flat, drawn in the post WWI years when more people were moving into the "middle-class" and living in high-rise flats without a lot of space.
[image: flat garden]

Comment: I am familiar with some of Heath Robinson's "Rube Goldberg" type drawings and I think they come from too early of an era.

Comment: @qwr That's a shame. Still, I'll take any excuse to look at WHR's drawings again!

Comment: Can I add another answer? Or should I delete this answer first? I may have found another possible illustrator.

Comment: idk standard procedure on this site. probably edit the answer.

Comment: @qwr I wonder if it's Bob Kerr? Have a look at these google results and see if any ring a bell? https://bit.ly/33Qe1Y3

Comment: @NiceOrc: A little late, but policy is to add multiple answers if you have multiple works. That way, any of them could be accepted (and it's clear which one is), while the others remain to cue later querents in.